# How to get to Hong Kong airport early morning from Yuen Long?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, hong-kong, taxis

I am going to stay in Yuen Long, Hong Kong, in the end of the month. Monday morning the 25th of May, I am flying from the airport at 8am. That means I'd like to be there at around 6am, and should probably leave from Yuen Long at 5am.

What is the best way to get there in the morning?

Are there some buses?

I'd like to avoid taxi if possible, but if it's the only option, that is also fine.

How much would I expect it to cost?

Comment: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Yuen+Long+Station,+Hong+Kong/Hong+Kong+International+Airport,+Chek+Lap+Kok,+Hong+Kong/@22.3716181,113.8972398,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x3403f0a6680f5f91:0xa49fcb3b1325d19d!2m2!1d114.034706!2d22.446113!1m5!1m1!1s0x3403e2f3cc46c69d:0xf9f590821892369e!2m2!1d113.918481!2d22.308047!2m3!6e1!7e2!8j1432533600!3e3) knows about Hong Kong buses, but the route it recommends seems to have been discontinued in 2013, so I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: @Gilles I won't recommend Google Maps for public transport information. Use the website established by the government instead: http://hketransport.gov.hk/

Comment: Eventually how do you do to airport on that day?

Comment: I took a taxi :) @Him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a taxi to the nearest MTR Airport Express train station, which would be Tsing Yi or Kowloon. Then take the train. It takes 24 minutes to get to the airport, and [service starts at 5:54. The fare is $60 (HKD) from Tsing Yi and $90 (HKD) from Kowloon](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/airport-express.html).

There are many buses that also go to the airport. You can find a full listing of them [here](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/to-from-airport/bus_to_hkia.html).

Comment: There's probably a much cheaper bus, and not that much slower, that can be reached with a similar taxi fare. There's probably a much cheaper all-bus option but it would be a lot slower.

Comment: Tsing Yi is much closer than Kowloon, but a taxi ride there might incur an extra toll for the bridge crossing; tolls are 55 HKD. Honestly, this answer is only a little less expensive (probably saves 30-40 HKD) than  taking a taxi straight to the airport, but takes significantly longer to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

Your time frame precludes much, if not all, travel on the MTR, as you probably know. Train service starts a few minutes before 6:00.

The easiest way to get there is to just take a taxi. It should cost around 350 HKD. Not cheap, but quick and simple.

You could also take a bus. Not sure where exactly you are - Yuen Long is big area - but you most likely want the E34 A or B. Both go from Yuen Long to the airport and start running about 5:10. Travel time will be 60-90 minutes. The fare will be less than 20 HKD. You can plan your bus route in detail by using [the official HK public transit planner](http://m.hketransport.gov.hk/routeSearch.aspx?lang=0). Be aware that if you have large or a lot of luggage, you may not be allowed to board the bus.